# Best way to communicate between RPi and Ubuntu Server

Tags: linux, bash, raspberry-pi

So I'm currently working on an automatic CO / Smoke detector that uses a RasPi as its controller. I want it to send out SMS alerts when a detection event happens. I would like it to work like this.

```
Sensor(s) > RPi > Main Server > SMS via sendmail
```

I am wondering how to keep a stable link between the RPi and my Server. I was thinking about using SSH and Ping along with Supervisord to keep everything working, however I also want to be able to test whether the script is working remotely with a command from the main server.

Does SSH and Ping seem like a good way of going about this? And if so, how can I ensure that the script on the RPi hasn't crashed, even if the device is responding to Pings?

Thanks

Edit: It doesn't need to be realtime communication, I was thinking of having it checked every 10s

Comment: You might find `netcat` or `nc` useful for sending short strings from one machine to another just in `bash` shell. You can also send a test string from your server to the Raspberry Pi and it can reverse it, or add 1, or something else and then send it back which will assure you that it is working.

Comment: So a little reading on `netcat` makes it seem viable, Will it only return the sent string? or will there be other information sent with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was suggesting you use something like this as your script on the Raspberry Pi.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

SVIP=192.168.0.9    # Server IP address
PORT=30000

################################################################################
# This function is called whenever the script exits or dies
################################################################################
function cleanup(){
   echo DEBUG: EXIT code running...
   # Kill the alive function we started in the background
   kill -9 $alivePID
}
trap cleanup EXIT

################################################################################
# This function runs continuously in the background answering "pings"
################################################################################
function alive(){
   echo DEBUG: Listening for pings on port $PORT
   while :; do
      echo "$RANDOM" | nc -l $PORT
      echo DEBUG: Ouch.
   done
}


################################################################################
# main function of script
################################################################################

# Start the ping responder in the background and note its PID so we can kill it
alive &
alivePID=$!

# Do whatever you want to do here - e.g. read temperatures
sleep 20
```

Start reading around 4 lines from the bottom. It starts a function called `alive()` in the background and gets its PID so it can be stopped on exit. The `alive()` function listens for *"pings"* using `netcat` and replies to each one with a random number.

If the script is stopped, it kills the `alive()` function and so it will no longer reply to pings.

On your server, you can then *"ping"* the Raspberry Pi by typing this command (replace RASPI_IP with the IP address of your Raspberry Pi):

```
echo "PING" | nc <RASPI_IP> 30000 ; echo $?
```

and you will get a random number and an exit code of `0` if the service is running on the Raspberry Pi, whereas you will get an exit code of `1` and no reply if the service on the Raspberry Pi is not running.